# After upgarde of windows 8.1 to windows 11 this doesn't work

Tags: xetex, pdf, compilation-error

After upgarde of windows 8.1 to windows 11 this doesn't work with TeXlive and WinEdt 10.3
but it previosuly worked; my command line in PdfTexify is as follows:

`latexmk -xelatex`

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "ideje20"
Startup Folder: D:\BitDownlD\WinEdt103\THdipl

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2023)
The top-level auxiliary file: ideje20.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file ideje20.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file ideje20.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file ideje20.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   latexmk -xelatex --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "ideje20.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\BitDownlD\WinEdt103\THdipl

Latexmk: File-database 'ideje20.fdb_latexmk' is of incompatible version, 3 v. current version 4
Initial Win CP for (console input, console output, system): (CP852, CP852, CP1250)
I changed them all to CP1250
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 4 Apr. 2023. Version 4.80.
Latexmk: applying rule 'xelatex'...
Rule 'xelatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  ideje20.aux
  ideje20.tex
Category 'changed_user':
  ideje20.tex
Category 'never_run':
  xelatex

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'xelatex'
------------
------------
Running 'xelatex -no-pdf --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 -recorder  "ideje20.tex"'
------------
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./ideje20.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-10-10>
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/accents/accents.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.
tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.d
ef)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.t
ex
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.te
x
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryf
iltered.code.tex))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.
def
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdf
mx.def
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common
-pdf.def))))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpat
h.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotoco
l.code.tex)) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.t
ex (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex
)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.t
ex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.cod
e.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.bas
ic.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.tri
gonometric.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.ran
dom.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.com
parison.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.bas
e.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rou
nd.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.mis
c.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.int
egerarithmetics.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.te
x)) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)

(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.
code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathcon
struct.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusa
ge.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.
code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphic
state.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransfo
rmations.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.c
ode.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects
.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathpro
cessing.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.
code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.c
ode.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.c
ode.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexterna
l.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.
code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspa
rency.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepattern
s.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.cod
e.tex)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.c
ode.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.cod
e.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-versi
on-0-65.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-versi
on-1-18.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.te
x)) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.c
ode.tex
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryploth
andlers.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.c
ode.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librar
ies/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tikz-cd/tikzlibrarycd.code.te
x
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librar
ies/tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librar
ies/tikzlibraryquotes.code.tex)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrow
s.meta.code.tex)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/xebabel.def)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-czech/czech.ldf))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/cs/babel-czech.t
ex) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/cslatex/base/il2enc.def)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/il2lmr.fd))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def))
) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty))
(./mypackage.sty) (./babyloniannum.sty
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
*** you should *not* be loading the inputenc package
*** XeTeX expects the source to be in UTF8 encoding
*** some features of other encodings may conflict, resulting in poor output.
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/numname/numname.sty))
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/enumitem/enumitem.sty)
(./ideje20.aux) (d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
*** you should *not* be loading the inputenc package
*** XeTeX expects the source to be in UTF8 encoding
*** some features of other encodings may conflict, resulting in poor output.

Overfull \hbox (4.25034pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 129--129
[]\slabikar Jakmile uleh-???ne¹, za-???vøe¹ oèi a uvi-???dí¹ své ruce, 
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm Santakku

The command name is D:\BitDownlD\texlive\2023\bin\windows\mktextfm
name = Santakku, rootname = Santakku, pointsize = 
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Santakku.mf

The command name is D:\BitDownlD\texlive\2023\bin\windows\mktexmf
Cannot find Santakku.mf.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

Missing character: There is no š ("161) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no ř ("159) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no ž ("17E) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no ř ("159) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no ě ("11B) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no č ("10D) in font slabikar!
Missing character: There is no č ("10D) in font slabikar!

! Package fontspec Error: The font "Santakku" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.183   \item r
               ozhodovat se na hraně zajímavého
? H

A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!

? 
Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
? Terminating on signal SIGBREAK(21)


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 2   Warnings: 1   Bad Boxes: 1
_____________________________________________________________________

                          kkkkkkkkkk
```

**NOW I'm GETTING THIS ERROR:**

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "ideje20"
Startup Folder: D:\BitDownlD\WinEdt103\THdipl

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2023)
The top-level auxiliary file: ideje20.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file ideje20.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file ideje20.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file ideje20.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   latexmk -xelatex -f --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "ideje20.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\BitDownlD\WinEdt103\THdipl

Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (852,852)
Initial Win CP for (console input, console output, system): (CP852, CP852, CP1250)
I changed them all to CP1250
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 4 Apr. 2023. Version 4.80.
Latexmk: Nothing to do for 'ideje20.tex'.
Latexmk: All targets (ideje20.pdf) are up-to-date
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  xdvipdfmx: gave an error in previous invocation of latexmk.
  xelatex: gave an error in previous invocation of latexmk.

D:\BitDownlD\texlive\2023\bin\windows\runscript.tlu:921: command failed with exit code 12:
perl.exe d:\BitDownlD\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\latexmk\latexmk.pl -xelatex -f --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "ideje20.tex"


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Seem you've installed font Santakku with Windows 8.1, but not with Windows 11. Install it again.

Comment: @cabohah That's a good advice. Could you give me a hint how to do that most easyly ?

Comment: it's a non standard font you found or bought previously and need to find again or copy from your old machine unrelated to tex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, what filename should I look for ? I.e. which extension and name ? Luckyly enough I have my old  disk in my new computer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've proceeded with installing `santakku` but not much; please see my next error I'm obtaining.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have also installed `straberry perl`: `$ type perl
perl is /cygdrive/d/BitDownlD/StrawberyPerl/perl/bin/perl`

Comment: what exactly did you do to install the font?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Dear Ulrike, I've sent you a private email from `pax0@seznam.cz`. I have downloaded [this](https://www.hethport.uni-wuerzburg.de/cuneifont/download/Santakku.zip) and installed `Santakku.ttf` and `SantakkuM.ttf` by doubleclicking on the file names. When trying to install them again, the system reported that they would be overwrited.

Comment: Try `fc-cache -f`, and be aware that my address is for a payed service. I write bills for private support.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer OK, I have run `fc-cahce -f` as well. How much would it be to repair my project ?