# A MWE of Santakku that doesn't work

Tags: xetex, font-encodings, latexmk, truetype

I have aksed a similar question [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698600/after-upgarde-of-windows-8-1-to-windows-11-this-doesnt-work), but now I have a MWE of my problem and I've also installed `Santakku.ttf` on my system.

The MWE is [here](https://pastebin.com/V9M1edBD) and the error I'm still getting is here:

```
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2021/04/29 v2.0v Standard LaTeX package
)
(d:/BitDownlD/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))

! Package fontspec Error: The font "Santakku" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.6 \DeclareTextFontCommand
                           {\textcuneiform}{\cuneiform}
? ^^Z
Type <return> to proceed, S to scroll future error messages,
R to run without stopping, Q to run quietly,
I to insert something, E to edit your file,
1 or ... or 9 to ignore the next 1 to 9 tokens of input,
H for help, X to quit.
?
! Emergency stop.
 ...

l.6 \DeclareTextFontCommand
                           {\textcuneiform}{\cuneiform}

A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!
```

Comment: try with `\newfontface{\cuneiform}[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Santakku.ttf}`. And try also with lualatex (it is less picky).

Comment: Please post your MWE here. Questions shouldn't rely on external links. You shouldn't be loading `fontenc` if you're using `fontspec`.

Comment: I can't see your MWE code on the external site. Please edit your question and paste the MWE on this site. On Windows, install fonts "for all users" (right-click option), or use the Path= option in fontspec package if the font is not installed.